# struts-config and message-resources : one Generic or one foreach langage

Tags: java, internationalization, struts, struts-config

I supposed it is a quite easy question but I never receive any clear answer.

I'am currently handling the internationalization of a struts application. After a long research, i found out that I was missing something int the struts-config.xml : the message-resources.

```
<struts-config>
    ...
    <message-resources parameter="my.bundle"/>
</struts-config>
```

I wanted to know if I need to add a  per langage ?
Something like :

```
<struts-config>
    ...
    <message-resources parameter="my.bundle"/>
    <message-resources parameter="my.bundle_en"/>
    <message-resources parameter="my.bundle_it"/>
</struts-config>
```

or maybe struts will link the default bundle with all its versions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you need only definition of your default resources for example

```
<message-resources parameter="com.bundle" null="false" />
```

and in your "res" directory create package "com" and put into it
*.properties files for every language.

```
bundle.properties
bundle_en.properties
bundle_de.properties
```

Default properties is use for your default language. And for situation, that any key isn't find in any language, struts use key from default bundle.